# How to count from split string in mysql like this example

Tags: php, mysql, database, split

how to manipulate data just look like this example in mysql

e.g.:

| icd | diagnose |
| --- | --- |
| A00 1 | diagnoseA00 1 |
| B34 2;A00 9;A39 5 | diagnoseB34 2;diagnoseA00 9;diagnoseA39 5 |

into

| icd | diagnose |
| --- | --- |
| A00 1 | diagnoseA00 1 |
| B34 2 | diagnoseB34 2 |
| A00 9 | diagnoseA00 9 |
| A39 5 | diagnoseA39 5 |

I was trying to use substring_index but it just took first string(1) or last string(-1) like table below

| icd | diagnose |
| --- | --- |
| A00 1 | diagnoseA00 1 |
| B34 2 | diagnoseB34 2;diagnoseA00 9;diagnoseA39 5 |

Comment: What have you tried? And please run `SELECT version();` to check MySQL version.

Comment: What is max. amount of values per one CSV value? What output do you need if the amount of separate values in solid values for `icd` and for `diagnose` differs?

Comment: FanoFN: like table that i make on my question. mysql version is 10.4.22-MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the explode() function on `icd` and `diagnose` and then merge the results with the return data

Read more  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       CASE WHEN icd LIKE '%;%' 
          THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(icd,';',seq),';',-1) 
          ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(icd,';',seq) END AS icd2,
       CASE WHEN diagnose LIKE '%;%' 
          THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(diagnose,';',seq),';',-1) 
          ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(diagnose,';',seq) END AS diagnose2
 FROM mytable m 
 CROSS JOIN seq_1_to_20 s;
```

One wonderful thing I found about MariaDB is that it has a [built-in sequence engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequence-storage-engine/). This makes some operation easier particularly on what you're trying to do. Your idea of using `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` is one of the right idea to tackle such task. However, it's not as straight forward as just with 1 `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` nor it doesn't require any other operation. In your case, you also need `CASE` expression. Add `DISTINCT` to return unique combination of extracted `icd` and `diagnose value` and you've got your expected output.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=f6d00b50f27ebe5383e48f30b3aeb017)

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with substring_index(). Check out my [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=99400ca411431dba30537b7663bc7663) for this.

> The only condition for this code to work fine is - you should have
> same number of sub-strings in both the fields on a row. Otherwise this
> would break.

**Sample:**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.diagnose, ';', n.n), ';', -1) value1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.icd, ';', n.n), ';', -1) value2
  FROM t t CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(t.diagnose) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.diagnose, ';', '')));
```